# How to store rest client logging in a variable in Spring Boot(logging)?

Tags: rest, spring-boot, logging, log4j, interceptor

I am working on a rest client in Spring boot. And I have enabled logging in spring boot by putting the underlying lines in the property file.

```
logging.level.org.apache.http=DEBUG
logging.level.org.apache.http.wire=DEBUG
```

After this I am getting the request sent as well as the response in the xml format in Spring boot log console.

But now I want to log the request logged in the database. Does spring boot provides any configuration with which I can get these logs in some variable and store request and response separately in DB tables.

Comment: you need a ControllerInterceptor. Kindly refer the following example to understand how it is done. http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-mvc-interceptor-example/

Comment: Do you mean you want to store logs in database?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Yes I have 2 tables one for requests and the other for response. So I want to store separate logs in those tables.

Comment: No, it doesn't work like that. If you want to store **log**, then this is **one** table, where all logs go. Otherwise, you need to intercept all request and response call in your question, like Pandey suggests.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov  Does spring boot provides any configuration to store logs in the DB without writing interceptors for every client I create. Because I will be creating SOAP as well as REST clients in my project.

Comment: @Anant666, it depends on logging framework, not on Spring.Interceptor may be written once if it is in a library-like. And it can be configured once if parts of configuration are shared across clients.